# Post-apocalyptic sci-fi book about a man with metal spikes in his head, like a crown of thorns, who is worshipped by rats

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

More than a decade ago, I began reading a book. The book got lost before I could finish, and I only remember very few, vague details.

I'm *pretty* sure it was set in a post-apocalyptic climate. Most likely post-atomic.

Also *pretty* sure there were lizard-people. Like those were the people mutated by nuclear fallout.

The main character was a lonely man. (Not a lizard)

Rats began to appear in greater numbers, and I think the man may have gone down to the sewer at one point.

The rats worshipped him.

He developed a terrible pain in his head, and began picking a lump on his forehead.

The lump turned out to be a metal spike. He withdrew several metal spikes from his head, each spike several inches long. They seemed to be positioned around his head like a crown of thorns.

I'm racking my brain trying to remember more, but I'm afraid that's all I've got to work with.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: The username checks out...

Comment: Mrs Frisby! As in Mrs Frisby and the Rats of NIMH? If it is then that's some blast from the past :-)

Comment: @noonand Yes! It's one of my favourite stories.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the novel *Deus Irae* by Philip K. Dick and Roger Zelazny.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_Irae):

> The Servants of Wrath leadership ask McMasters to find Lufteufel and paint his mural. En route, we learn about the absence of national communications systems after the widespread destruction caused by nuclear warfare. McMasters and other seekers encounter mutant lizards, birds and insects who have evolved sentience, as well as the "Big C", a decaying artificial intelligence that also survived the war; it survives by consuming humans for their trace elements.
>
> While trying to remove shrapnel from his forehead, Lufteufel loses consciousness from loss of blood, at which point his intellectually challenged "daughter", Alice, tries to remove some of the blood using a shirt. This leaves a bloody imprint on the fabric. Alice keeps the shirt because it is the only remaining likeness of his face, leaving her with the only true relic of the God of Wrath, evoking the Christian legend of the veil of Veronica and the artifact known as the Shroud of Turin.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to specify the ways in which this matches the book described in the question, and any ways in which it doesn't. Specifying the year in which this book was published would be helpful too.

Comment: Yes this is it. I had forgotten the scenes with the rats and the metal spikes, but then Deus Irae is such an odd book that I had forgotten many aspects of its plot.

Comment: The killer rats had a single psychic group consciousness. "It" was used to killing people with guns, who basically couldn't hurt it. But as they mocked him, he threw a grenade which terrified them into believing he was a god.

Comment: @OwenReynolds " he threw a grenade which terrified them into believing he was a god." Making it a *Holy Hand Grenade*?

Comment: Huzzah! I recognized the title right away as soon as I read your content! This is it, without a doubt. Thank you!

Comment: @MrsFrisby You may want to mark it as the correct answer then, for the benefit of both the answer author and the readers :-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Can you tell me how to do that? I'm new and on mobile, so I'm not familiar with the flags and functions. 

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica hah I think, after scrolling back up, that I figured it out; assuming the big checkmark is what I'm looking for. 